# logstash filter how to create two (or above ) outputs for the one input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am getting via http poller one json

```
  {
 "id":12345
 "name":"",
 "lastname":"",
 "age":12,
 "address":{"city":"XXXX" , "street":"ZZZZ" }
 }
```

and I would like this to generate two document in my output :

person :

```
 {
"id":12345
"name":"",
"lastname":"",
"age":12
  }
```

address :

```
 {
"city":"XXXX" , 
"street":"ZZZZ" 
  }
```

meaning I got one event in the input

in the input  phase getting one input :

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test1 => "http://localhost:8080"
    }
}
```

in the filter phase I would like to :

1. create person event (tag it as P)
2. create address event (tag it as A)

in the output phase I would like to :

1. send P to P type in ES
2. send A to A type in ES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with the [`clone` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html).

First, you need to install the plugin which is not bundled by default:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-clone
```

Then you can modify your Logstash config like this:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test1 => "http://localhost:8080"
    }
    type => "A"
  }
}
filter {
    clone {
        clones => [ "P" ]
        add_tag => [ "P" ]
    }
    if [type] == "P" {
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "address" ]
        }
    } else {
        mutate {
            add_tag => [ "A" ]
            remove_field => [ "id", "name", "lastname", "age" ]
        }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        document_type => "%{type}"
    }
}
```

Comment: can u also make for each url type ? and not one for all the urls ?

Comment: You can use several `http_poller` inputs :-)

Comment: Yes the problem I have with puller is the ability to work without ssl verification which I need , any proposal?

Comment: Using [`ssl_certificate_validation => false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html#plugins-inputs-http_poller-ssl_certificate_validation) maybe?

Comment: Nope , according to the official plugin it’s not supported and I can’t find one who does 

Comment: Since this question is closed I suggest you create a new one with your new problem.